# Java array --> string, but .equals() not working (Or: is there an easier way to do this?)

Tags: java, arrays, string, equals

I'm working on a program which takes in a file with the name of an item of produce, its type (Broccoli, Vegetable), and then another item and its type on a different line.  It randomly takes 3 items and puts them in a "boxOfProduce" array.  I turn that into a string separated by commas, and then that into a different list.  I look at the items at indexes 1,3,5 to see if its a fruit or a vegetable and increase the according count.

But the count is staying at 0 and not increasing.  What could I be doing wrong?  Or is there an easier was to do this?

```
Random random = new Random();

String firstProduceType = produce[random.nextInt(size)];
String secondProduceType = produce[random.nextInt(size)];
String thirdProduceType = produce[random.nextInt(size)];

BoxOfProduce boxOfProduce = new BoxOfProduce(firstProduceType, secondProduceType, thirdProduceType);

String produceString = firstProduceType + ", " + secondProduceType + ", " + thirdProduceType;
String[] produceStringArray = produceString.split(",");

int fruitCount = 0;
int vegetableCount = 0;

System.out.println(produceStringArray);

if (produceStringArray[1].trim().equals("Fruit")) {
    fruitCount += 1;
}
else if (produceStringArray[1].trim().equals("Vegetable")) {
    vegetableCount += 1;
}

if (produceStringArray[3].trim().equals("Fruit")) {
    fruitCount += 1;
}
else if (produceStringArray[3].trim().equals("Vegetable")) {
    vegetableCount += 1;
}

if (produceStringArray[5].trim().equals("Fruit")){
    fruitCount += 1;
}
else if (produceStringArray[5].trim().equals("Vegetable")) {
    vegetableCount += 1;
}
```

EDIT: firstProduceType, secondProduceType, and thirdProduceType are entirely random, so they'll be (item, type).

Comment: Do you really want to do this `String produceString = firstProduceType + ", " + secondProduceType + ", " + thirdProduceType;
String[] produceStringArray = produceString.split(",");`. Adding commans and then removing it. Why don't you directly put them into array?

Comment: Also can you post the content of the first,second and third produce type?

Answer (score 0):

Try lowercasing everything as well. Equals works if strings are equal

Also you can use

```
String[] produceStringArray = {firstProduceType, ...};
```

Should be more safe

Also I think it should be `produce[random.nextInt(size-1)];`

As indexing starts from 0